# Creating memorization algorithm given a fibonacci recursive function

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci, memoization

For a school assignment, we have to create a memorized `fibonacci` function that reuses the recursive implementation of computing the `fibonacci`.

What is a good way to design our memorized function such that it takes advantage of an already existing function? This is my implementation so far:

Base class:

```
    public int computeFibonacci(int position) {
        assertPosition(position);

        if (position < 2) {
            return 1;
        }
        return computeFibonacci(position - 1) + computeFibonacci(position - 2);
    }
```

Inherited class:

```
    public int computeFibonacci(int position) {
        assertPosition(position);

        if (position < 2) {
            return 1;
        }

        if (this.memoizedList.containsKey(position)) {
            return this.memoizedList.get(position);
        }
        int result = super.computeFibonacci(position - 1) + super.computeFibonacci(position - 2);
        this.memoizedList.put(position, result);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: you wanna read this post for optimal solution - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-for-program-for-fibonacci-numbers/

Comment: You don't need to call `super` implementation. If you call `super` implementation then you won't be able to make use of memoized values.

Answer (score 2):

There is a confusion about reusing the recursive implementation in Base Class.
If you call the recursive implementation, it will recursively calculate fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) = ..., which is conflict with memo function. Memo function tries to save time for calculated ones.
For memo:

```
public int computeFibonacci(int position) {
        assertPosition(position);

        if (position < 2) {
            return 1;
        }

        if (this.memoizedList.containsKey(position)) {
            return this.memoizedList.get(position);
        }
        int result = computeFibonacci(position - 1) + computeFibonacci(position - 2);
        this.memoizedList.put(position, result);
        return result;
    }
```

For example, you try to print the first 1000 elements in fibonacci, memo function will save time on calculated ones.

Answer (score 1):

Your sub-class version doesn't take full advantage of the cached values. For example, if you call `computeFibonacci(5)`, and `memoizedList` doesn't contain that key, you would call `super.computeFibonacci(4)` and `super.computeFibonacci(3)` even if they are already cached. Instead, you should call `super.computeFibonacci(5)`.

```
public int computeFibonacci(int position) {
    assertPosition(position);

    if (position < 2) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (this.memoizedList.containsKey(position)) {
        return this.memoizedList.get(position);
    } else {
        int result = super.computeFibonacci(position);
        this.memoizedList.put(position, result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this function does not _reimplement_ the original computeFibonacci. If reimplementing the original function is superfluous.

Comment: @JoopEggen I'm not sure what you mean by that. My suggestion for the sub-class's `computeFibonacci` obtains the value stored in the cache (if available) or calls the super class implementation otherwise.

Comment: Oh it was praise in a way, as the OP repeated the implementation of the original method. Your answer is halfways to a general solution for memoisation.